# Bash script to read a log file for a string the executes a command on 1 field from the log line when string is found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to put together a bash script that will read a log and execute a command when a string is found. The script needs to be able to find the string as the log is running, print 1 field from the log line, strip the first and last characters from the field, then move the return somewhere else. What I have so for but it is not working. The variable "error" is the file name in /srv/files that I need moved to /tmp/error when the log reports it as an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
for error in $(tail -fn0 /var/log/test-$(date +%Y%m%d).log | grep FAILED | awk '{print $8}' | cut -d "'" -f); do mv /srv/files/$error /tmp/error; done
```

Comment: What is the error message? If no error what is the result of running your script?

Comment: Have you checked your script in [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and looked at what it outputs?

Comment: The error from the log is FAILED. The script just needs to monitor the for that string. If it doesn't see it, it should do nothing.